# not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to setup zookeeper on ec2 two instances. as given [here](http://www.elcct.com/installing-apache-zookeeper-cluster-on-ubuntu-13-10/) and [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Setting+Up+an+External+ZooKeeper+Ensemble).
I am trying to run zookeeper which fails with an error:
command: `bin/zkCli.sh -server localhost:2181`

```
> 2015-03-15 00:22:35,644 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeper@438] - Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=30000 watcher=org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain$MyWatcher@3ff0efca
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
2015-03-15 00:22:35,671 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@975] - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
JLine support is enabled
2015-03-15 00:22:35,677 [myid:] - WARN  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1102] - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTING) 0] 2015-03-15 00:22:36,796 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@975] - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-03-15 00:22:36,797 [myid:] - WARN  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1102] - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
```

zoo.cfg as bellow

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
server.2=<My ec2 private IPs>:2889:3889
```

also I have created myId file as on both ec2 instances - `/var/lib/zookeeper/myid`

I also tried to edit /ect/hosts file but still facing the same issue.
also how I can start both of the zookeeper instances by 1 command?

Note: Server get started successfully if I tried with `bin/zkCli.sh start` command.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure the zk is accessible on port 2181? `Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181` sounds like connectivity issues with zk. Try running `telnet localhost 2181` and post the output.here.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer I have started zk using `bin/zkCli.sh start` and then tried `telnet localhost 2181` gives message as `telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused`

Comment: Cool... that's the issue. Your ZK is not accepting any connections on port 2181. Check your ZK settings... you should ensure that you **MUST NOT** get  `telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused` before troubleshooting any further.

Comment: Zoo.cfg file has clientPort =2181, is there anything else I need to configure

Comment: post the output of command `netstat -punta | grep 2181`

Comment: tried with given command but no output came

Comment: Correct Again... your ZK it not listening on port 2181. Had it been working fine, you should have received some output for above mentioned `netstat` command. I ma not a ZK expert. However, Now I am removing the `amazon-ec2` tag as this has nothing to do with Amazon EC2.

Comment: Your command is wrong `bin/zkCli.sh start` and ZooKeeper server is probably not running. You should use `bin/zkServers.sh start` instead.

Answer (score 3):

look zk log zookeeper.out，if there have connection limit error, configure the following to zoo.cfg.

```
# the maximum number of client connections.
# increase this if you need to handle more clients
maxClientCnxns=60
```

Answer (score 2):

This is temporary error , for mine after some time , It gone away :-

This is my zoo.conf file ::-

```
Dir=../data
clientPort=2181
tickTime=2000
initLimit=5
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred when I forgot to `run% ZOOKEEPER_HOME% \ bin \ zkserver.cmd`

By running, the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Correct this property on the server.properties

default would be localhost change it to match the zookeeper server starup ip and port

zookeeper.connect=0.0.0.0:2181

Answer (score -1):

It may be cache. Restarting the server solved this issue.